# Pegar somente valores depois da vírgula em um double

Tags: dart, matemática

Qual a melhor forma em Dart de pegar o valor após a vírgula/ponto em um `double`?

Ex:
double x = 21.16;

Como pego só o 16?

Como pego só o 21?

Estou usando o `x.truncate();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [`truncate()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/double/truncate.html) é uma forma de pegar a parte inteira , o [`round()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/toInt.html) é outra, mas para este caso o melhor seria o [`toInt()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/toInt.html).

Sempre use a documentação para conhecer mais da API disponível para a linguagem.

Para pegar a parte decimal é pura matemática, não é programação (na verdade o grosso do que se aprende em programação é matemática, alguma coisa que é alguma novidade dentro disso, mas sempre é matemática, é que este caso matemática pura), faça a subtração do valor total com a parte inteira, o resultado obviamente será a parte decimal.

Só lembrando que [`double` não serve para valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). [Veja o `decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal).

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

Comment: Poxa mano, muito obrigado. Realmente não tinha pensado nessa logica que tirar a parte inteira, Muito obrigado mesmo!